# CSS3 Transform Rotate3D - On Hover, Force FULL Transform?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exceptionalish/6udv405h/2/).

```
.box:hover {
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}
```

I'm using some CSS3 to get the card flip effect on some parts of my site. I have no issues with this in any Windows browsers, but I'm getting reports from some Mac users that the rotation is getting stuck and won't flip over completely. It looks like in those browsers, when doing a 3d transformation it appears that the "hitbox" for hover is transformed along with the element and content (as it gets close to rotating 90 degrees, the hitbox for the element approaches 1px width).

I could be wrong about what's happening or maybe there's a better fix than what I have in mind, but I was looking to hopefully work around this issue by causing the full transition/animation to play out as soon as the mouse triggered the hover. This way, even if the hitbox for the hover does change size, the elements will finish flipping over.

Is this possible with just CSS3? Or should I look into a javascript solution?

Comment: Why don't you just wrap it and put the hover on the wrapper instead? `.wrapper:hover .box { ... }` https://jsfiddle.net/6udv405h/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with a wrapper and put the hover on the wrapper. I tested on FF and chrome on Mac

https://jsfiddle.net/6udv405h/3/

```
.wrapper:hover .box {
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hadn't even thought of that, don't know why haha. I'll give this a shot a little later today.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.box').mouseover(function () {
            var box = $(this)
            $(box).addClass('hovered');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(box).removeClass('hovered');
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Little bit of Jquery solved my issue. I would still have preferred to use only CSS, so please reach out to me if you have a better solution without using JS.